# Windows corrupts my filesystem on each boot (windows & linux repair apps already tried)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Installation done in order:

- Windows 7
- Ubuntu 12
  (so far so good)
- I re-installed Windows 7, over the last one. This destroyed the GRUB so i (regretfully) installed a now unknown windows bootloader, using a windows third party app.
  (everything still working good with the new windows bootloader, which loaded both Windows and Ubuntu).
- Un-installed the ubuntu 12, used the partition for data storage and installed a new ubuntu 17, on a different partition of a different hard-drive.
- Currently a grub is loading correctly, if i just choose ubunut, everything is ok, as many times as i like but if i choose windows 7, the machine loads a Windows Bootloader with 2 options. Windows and another called "NeoSmart Linux" which if chosen loads a "GRUB4DOS", which is a deadend. If i select Windows its loads correctly, but when i reboot and in the GRUB i THEN choose Ubuntu, it fails to mount the corrupted disk and loads initramfs (Busybox).

I can run fscheck on my unmouted linux partition and if i THEN reboot Ubuntu THEN loads correctly. Everytime i load Windows i have to go through this same process.

What i have tried so far:

- Using a Windows Live Disk i run "bootrec.exe /fixboot" and "bootrec.exe /fixmbr", after this i ended up the same Windows Bootloader described before.
- After this, i run an Ubuntu Live Disk, and installed the "boot-repair", tried to repair everything and ended up AGAIN with the GRUB and Windows Boot Loader with the same original behaviour.

Here are the summary of the partitions generated by boot-repair : https://share.riseup.net/#XGlXNlQ0zaKQK0ZC3k0n2w

Comment: why did you use an extended partition on sdb if you only have 2 partitions? where did you install grub?

Comment: grub has to be installed to the device (/sda) .